# Specify Which Table to Scrape on Page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The page in question is: http://stats.nba.com/player/2544/shots-dash/?Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Playoffs&LastNGames=6&sort=FGM&dir=1

and I'm trying to scrape the 5th table.

I started by trying to get the column headers first by doing:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://stats.nba.com/player/2544/shots-dash/?Season=2017-18&SeasonType=Playoffs&LastNGames=6'
html = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

column_headers = [th.getText() for th in soup.findAll('tr')[1].findAll('th')]

data_rows = soup.findAll('tr')[1:]
```

but then I got a `IndexError: list index out of range` error and my `data_rows` came up empty.

Which in turn made me realize that all the tags for each table on this page are identical and so I'm not really sure how to specify the exact table I want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website you gave is built within `Angular` witch is a `JavaScript framework`. So, loading the HTML before `Angular` fill it up, will give you only the skull of the website witch is a basic HTML without the data you need.

So, to answer to your question, you must know the logic behind your target, witch is an application built with `Angular`. With a little bit of research you'll find that Angular is basically an API consumer.

Head on the requests your browser made, you'll find an API endpoint, that `Angular` uses to fill the tables of the link you gave.

Here is an example of how you can parse the API endpoint and get your desired data:

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request 


# API endpoint where Angular gets the data and it'll fill the tables with
url = 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/playerdashptshots?DateFrom=&DateTo=&GameSegment=&LastNGames=6&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PerMode=PerGame&Period=0&PlayerID=2544&Season=2017-18&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Playoffs&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision='

# The server behind the website checks the headers
# So you need to add to your request at least 
# a valid Cookie and a user agent
headers = {
    'Cookie': 'ak_bmsc=98B4FD680504382D1BE219CE963DE520ADDE6D86FF260000CD220B5B87B91E5E~ploZrwUVSrpu3HO/7DratALkZS/cK+SOZ9zMvNJNvJ6u/dYH50zISBdr3kK2S6ifBH/zXh9Z8oBFFeq1so2FGYfl29Zob9z065l/0caXBy5CNT3gOCn3OojgRPe7j1LLDThGl7eYQju8bl+1dO24vr5r9U+YngrmtlXpUPX+IT6Z7YoJPXP9YHmx1FMCyr7FOKmTyJL7js91F1pGVKGEOE/plhHEB4P7sq3B0uRzWWWcc=; s_cc=true; s_fid=5CA44E6CD67BA096-0F573C9E17BE0B09; s_sq=%5B%5BB%5D%5D; bm_sv=682C33C8686155B97E1B1692275AF96F~HweJkyeagLOu7iHDyl4xgtUAYOpT0NW49tH2OZpG93uH9+RTvrfGREItatT/72/WL3cY/k2VeYr/tDO1feFxAvO+Xe8fzIw2JOH4A/0lRXqp709dcJb53l9AytLTOgoHaQ4UG7rjPBPyMSoFFeJ3tg==',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36',
}
# Building the request
request = Request(url, headers=headers)
with urlopen(request, timeout=3) as f:
    data = f.read().decode('utf8')

# Convert the JSON to a valid Python dict
data_json = json.loads(data)
# Get the data of the 5th table
desired_table = data_json['resultSets'][5]
# Get the headers of the 5th table
data_headers = desired_table.get('headers')

# Print them out ...
# PS: You need to find how to pretty print them
# Like what the website do
# For example: Convert some floats to percentage etc..
for elm in desired_table.get('rowSet'):
    for head, val in zip(data_headers, elm):
        print('{0} : {1}'.format(head, val))
    print('#'*20)
```

output (first row of the 5th table):

```
PLAYER_ID : 2544
PLAYER_NAME_LAST_FIRST : James, LeBron
SORT_ORDER : 1
GP : 6
G : 1
CLOSE_DEF_DIST_RANGE : 0-2 Feet - Very Tight
FGA_FREQUENCY : 0.007
FGM : 0.0
FGA : 0.17
FG_PCT : 0.0
EFG_PCT : 0.0
FG2A_FREQUENCY : 0.007
FG2M : 0.0
FG2A : 0.17
FG2_PCT : 0.0
FG3A_FREQUENCY : 0.0
FG3M : 0.0
FG3A : 0.0
FG3_PCT : None
####################
...
```

And in order to understand how you can pretty print those values, the website uses a template with tags [ visit this [link](http://stats.nba.com/templates/angular/tables/player/player-shots-dash.html) ].

The interesting part is :

```
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ng-repeat="(i, row) in page" index="{{ ::i }}">
      <td class="player">
        <span ng-if="title==='Overall'">{{ ::row.SHOT_TYPE }}</span>
        <span ng-if="title==='GeneralShooting'">{{ ::row.SHOT_TYPE }}</span>
        <span ng-if="title==='ShotClockShooting'">{{ ::row.SHOT_CLOCK_RANGE }}</span>
        <span ng-if="title==='ClosestDefenderShooting'">{{ ::row.CLOSE_DEF_DIST_RANGE }}</span>
        <span ng-if="title==='ClosestDefender10ftPlusShooting'">{{ ::row.CLOSE_DEF_DIST_RANGE }}</span>
        <span ng-if="title==='DribbleShooting'">{{ ::row.DRIBBLE_RANGE }}</span>
        <span ng-if="title==='TouchTimeShooting'">{{ ::row.TOUCH_TIME_RANGE }}</span>
      </td>
      <td>{{ ::row.GP }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.G }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FGA_FREQUENCY | percent }}%</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FGM | permode:params.PerMode }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FGA | permode:params.PerMode }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG_PCT | percent }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.EFG_PCT | percent }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG2A_FREQUENCY | percent }}%</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG2M | permode:params.PerMode }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG2A | permode:params.PerMode }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG2_PCT | percent }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG3A_FREQUENCY | percent }}%</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG3M | permode:params.PerMode }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG3A | permode:params.PerMode }}</td>
      <td>{{ ::row.FG3_PCT | percent }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Finally, be good with the website and don't flood or spam it.

**Edit:** I found this [API schema](https://github.com/kshvmdn/nba.js/blob/master/docs/api/STATS.md) provided by the website itself on Github that explains the data in the API endpoints. You can read it in order to know how to deal with the JSON's ouputs.

Comment: Wow this is incredible. Thanks so much!

Comment: hey so do you know how to get around a `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error? seems to be throwing it at the `data_json = json.loads(data)` for some reason. Thanks

Comment: @dejsdukes this means that your data is not a valid JSON data.